# How to make all combination of features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I am trying to improve my machine learning system by combining my features. I have written some code to generate all of the combinations of my features. However, it seems very inefficient. Is there a way to do this faster?

```
allcomb=[]
for i in range(pow(2,len(features))):
    com=[]
    for j in (range(len(features))):
        if((i&(1<<j))==1):
            com.append(features[j])
    allcomb.append(com)
```

Comment: Reason for downvote ?

Comment: I didn't down vote your question, but check out [StackOverflow's how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some insights.

Comment: Kindly give me some insight like how my question is bad ? I don't see anything wrong here,I was poilte and ask genuine question. Can you tell me whats wrong with this @dantiston Thank you

Comment: Did you read the page? **Search and research** what did you find during your research on this question? Why didn't it work? **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem** You're looking specifically for a problem with your combinations algorithm -- the fact that you're using it with ML is either not represented properly in your title or not relevant. **Proof read** You're missing a lot of punctuation and your English isn't perfect. That's okay -- but you should either ask for help prior to posting or mention it in your question to invite others to edit your question. etc.

Comment: @dantiston Thankyou. I am new here,will keep all this in mind before asking next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check out Python's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) package; that will help make your code more efficient and readable.  You can do most of the combinatoric things you want with that package.

One great advantage is that you get a *generator* for the sequence of combinations, so you don't have to store them all at once in a list.

Also, do note that you have an inherently slow process.  If you want all possible combinations of 16 features, that's 2**16 times through any processing loop.  You're already at 64K iterations, and that will double for every added feature.

Can you consider doing a PCA (Principal Component Analysis) and feature reduction before you get into any heavy processing?

Comment: After PCA and Feature selection I got 20 features so how can I optimize to check the combination ? Is it even possible to go lesser than O(n*2^n) ?

Comment: From what little you've described so far, no -- you're stuck with that 2^n.  Are you worried about the **O** complexity, or about actual execution time?  If it's the time, then is there anything you can do to cache partial results from simpler runs, or use results from one test to entirely avoid another?